# Why is my round function not working when I have a float in Python? I tried many methods online, but none work

Tags: python

I was working on a project where I could find out a users balance with a monthly payment, interest and term of the payment. But when I look through the code my round function shows an error. I looked online and found different methods like formatting and such but none seemed to work. It all seems correct, I asked a few classmates and they can't figure out the problem either. Help is appreciated. If you want me to specify more you can comment and I can get to it as soon as possible.

Link for the file used in the program: https://vsbworld-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/1253540_learn_vsb_bc_ca/ESbQS3z58CdBspGmKN74IDABH-mlT7B7tN_ZFuFtq77fpQ?e=f15c8c

```
""" 

Created on Mon Nov 28 10:19:18 2022 

Ask how much they can afford to spend per month, then give a list of cars they can buy. 

@author: ... 

""" 

#List Library
count = 0 
price = 0
make = [] 
model = [] 
year = [] 
fuel = [] 
hp = [] 
cylinders = [] 
transmission = [] 
driveTrain = [] 
doors = [] 
category = [] 
size = [] 
body = [] 
highwayMPG = [] 
cityMPG = [] 
popularity = [] 
msrp = [] 

#File Search 

with open("car data.csv") as file: 

    #Set information into seperate lists 

    for line in file: 
        carInformation = line.split(",") 
        make.append(carInformation[0]) 
        model.append(carInformation[1]) 
        year.append(carInformation[2]) 
        fuel.append(carInformation[3]) 
        hp.append(carInformation[4]) 
        cylinders.append(carInformation[5]) 
        transmission.append(carInformation[6]) 
        driveTrain.append(carInformation[7]) 
        doors.append(carInformation[8]) 
        category.append(carInformation[9]) 
        size.append(carInformation[10]) 
        body.append(carInformation[11]) 
        highwayMPG.append(carInformation[12]) 
        cityMPG.append(carInformation[13]) 
        popularity.append(carInformation[14]) 
        msrp.append(carInformation[-1]) 

#Remove the first element of the list 

make.remove(make[0]) 
model.remove(model[0]) 
year.remove(year[0]) 
fuel.remove(fuel[0]) 
hp.remove(hp[0]) 
cylinders.remove(cylinders[0]) 
transmission.remove(transmission[0]) 
driveTrain.remove(driveTrain[0]) 
doors.remove(doors[0]) 
category.remove(category[0]) 
size.remove(size[0]) 
body.remove(body[0]) 
highwayMPG.remove(highwayMPG[0]) 
cityMPG.remove(cityMPG[0]) 
popularity.remove(popularity[0]) 
msrp.remove(msrp[0]) 

# introduction 

print("Hello, What is your name?") 
name = input() 

print("Hello " + name + ", I am Car Bot, I can help you select a car that fits all your needs.") 
print("Would you like to purchase a car? (y) Yes, (n) No. ") 
purchase = input().lower().strip(" .,!?abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxz") 
if purchase == "n": 
    print("Ok, Thank You, for using Car Bot") 

# when someone wants to buy a car 

if purchase == "y": 

    print("OK! LETS GET STARTED!!") 
    print("Would you like to Finance or Finance?") 
    purchase_selection = input().lower() 

    # if they want to Pay by Finance 

    if purchase_selection == "finance":
        payment = float(input("How much can you put down monthly? "))
        term = float(input("How long is the term you are willing to pay the loan? "))
        interest = float(input("What is the interest rate in your area? "))
        r = interest
        n = 12.0
        
        # payment calulation and print
        price = payment * (1.0 - (1.0 + r/n)**-(n * term) * (n/r)
        price = round(price, 2)
        # list of cars that can be purchased
        for cost in msrp:
            if float(cost) <= price:
                print("ID(" + str(count) + ")" + make[count] + " " + model[count] + " $" + str(cost)
            count+= 1
        
        # for more info about the cars
```

Comment: Just fixed a little variable error by correcting one of my variables (askingPrice) to (cost)

Comment: A better way to remove the first element of a list is to do `make.pop(0)`.  Even better is not to create that element at all, by checking for the header row in your `for line in file:` loop.

Comment: Don't round the price itself.  Instead, use formatting to print it rounded: `f"{price:.2f}"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Or read the first line before the loop. `file.readline()`

Comment: What version of python? Older versions had a rounding issue that was later resolved

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the advice, I was rounding it because if I format it all the numbers might be messed up. Like some prices are 2000 while others are 100000. The methods I found for formatting had too many decimals for one price. and none for another price.

Comment: @GlockByte It is the most recent version of Python 3 on Spyder.

Comment: Have you looked into using a decimal rather than float? Once you cast to a float, your precision is lost. Has your research into the issue brought you towards reading about floating point imprecision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that works.  Your CSV file has quoted fields with embedded commas, so your "split" was not sufficient.  I've changed this to use the `csv` module, since it can handle quoting.  I've also converted the MSRP column to float right away.

Your interest/payment computation was wrong.  I've fixed that.  It seems kind of silly to ask "do you want to buy a car", since they would not have run the program if they didn't.

```
import sys
import csv

#File Search 

with open("car data.csv") as file: 
    carinfo =  list(csv.DictReader(file))

for c in carinfo:
    c['MSRP'] = float(c['MSRP'])

# Introduction 

name = input("Hello, What is your name? ") 

print("Hello " + name + ", I am Car Bot, I can help you select a car that fits all your needs.") 
purchase = input("Would you like to purchase a car? (y) Yes, (n) No. ").lower()

if purchase == "n": 
    print("Ok, Thank You, for using Car Bot") 
    sys.exit(0)

# when someone wants to buy a car 

print("OK! LETS GET STARTED!!") 
purchase_selection = input("Would you like to Finance or Finance?").lower()

# if they want to Pay by Finance 

if purchase_selection == "finance":
    payment = float(input("How much can you put down monthly? "))
    term = float(input("How long is the term you are willing to pay the loan? (months)"))
    interest = float(input("What is the interest rate in your area? "))
    r = interest/1200.0

    # payment calulation and print
    r1 = (1.0 + r)**term
    price = payment * (r1 - 1) / (r * r1)
    print(f"You can afford a car worth ${price:.2f}")

    # list of cars that can be purchased
    for count,car in enumerate(carinfo):
        if car['MSRP'] <= price:
            print(f"ID({count}) {car['Make']} {car['Model']} ${car['MSRP']:.2f}")
    
    # for more info about the cars
```